# Android notification checking from service?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm currently writing an app, what has an on-boot service. This service simply pops up a notification after a time, and update it in given periods with new info. Currently there's no need for any further battery saving, I just want the update sequence to work.

I've hit a problem tho. Created the boot BroadcastReceiver what then starts my Service. It it, I do the work via a Timer and a TimerTask. But as I saw, there's no easy way to check if the notification was deleted, and thus not try to update it, but re-create it.

What I want to do:

```
private Notification n;

NotifTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        if(n.exists){
           // Update notification
        }else{
           n = Notification.Builder(context).[customize it].build();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the service's onStart, set up a timer what runs this task every 10 seconds.
Now, my question is: is there any way to do the "n.exists" part easily, without intents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post a notification and this notification already exists, it will just get updated with the new information. If it doesn't exist it will be created. I don't think you need to do anything special to get the behaviour you want.

From the [documentation for NotificationManager.notifiy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html):

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification
>   with the same id has already been posted by your application and has
>   not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Comment: Problem is, that I don't use NotificationManager.notify() as it's deprecated on the target SDKs.

Comment: Huh? What is your target SDK? I don't see anywhere that `NotificationManager.notify()` is deprecated. How are you posting your notifications?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I was fiddling with this yesterday (target SDK is 11-16), and it told me that the usual, GB-style of building notifications has been deprecated, but not the posting :D Mixed the two up, my fault! And thanks for the answer, let's check if it works...